# PL/SQL procedure compiles with a minor error need assistance

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I have had to change the format of my procedure I almost have it I know that I'm close

I keep getting PLS-00103 Error.

I need assistance I believe its something small.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TRANSFER_MANY_DOCS
AS
( column_A IN TABLE_2.column_1%TYPE;
  column_B IN TABLE_2.column_2%TYPE;
  column_C IN TABLE_2.column_3%TYPE;
  column_D IN TABLE_2.column_4%TYPE;
  column_E IN TABLE_2.column_5%TYPE;
  column_F IN TABLE_2.column_6%TYPE;
 
 CURSOR SEL_RW_VE IS
 SELECT  column_A, column_B,column_C,column_D, column_E, column_F
 FROM SEL_RW_VE
 
BEGIN /* 1 */
    OPEN SEL_RW_VE;
    LOOP 
        FETCH SEL_RW_VE INTO column_A, column_B,column_C, column_D, column_E, column_F;
        IF SEL_RW_VE%NOTFOUND
        THEN
        COMMIT;
        EXIT;
        END IF;
        BEGIN /* 2 */
            INSERT INTO USER.TABLE_2 (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, column_6)
            EXCEPTION
             WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
              THEN
                BEGIN /* 3 */ 
                    INSERT INTO USER.TABLE_2 (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5, column_6)
                    VALUES column_A, column_B,column_C,column_D, column_E, column_F FROM USER.LMS_EXTRACT;
                END;  /* 3 */
        END;  /* 2 */
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE SEL_RW_VE;
END;
```

Comment: (A) What is the full error message? `PLS-00103` is incomplete without the full message. (B) You're missing a `;` at the end of your cursor definition. (C) Your first INSERT statement is incomplete - it looks like you forgot to finish it.

Comment: (D) You have a random `(` at the beginning of line 3. (E) Your `column_A-F` variable definitions shouldn't have the `IN` keyword.

Comment: thank you let me try these fixes

Comment: OK I made those changes now im getting the following error     22/2      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FROM" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior 
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: @LamontG - the latest error refers to character 2 of line 22 of your modified code, so you need to look at that - we can't see it. Your original code has some additional problems: (F)  an insert won't throw no_data_found; ang (G) your second insert is mixing `insert ... values(...)` and `insert ... select ...` syntax. `USER` is also a reserved word but presumably you've changed your real schema name, along with some of the table and column names.

Comment: yes @AlexPoole I had to change the real table name and columns I have corrected several minor errors since posting it but now i have received new instructions that i don't need the exception and i have to put one more insert into a new another table with the when others clause